# Best practices for SEO of YouTube video content

Tags: seo, youtube

What are best practices for search engine optimization of YouTube video content? By that I mean filling in descriptions, titles, tags and so on. I can't find good information about this on the internet, about which keywords to use, optimal/maximum lenght of texts and other (?) issues

Answer (score 1):

The things you mentioned are a good start.

Something that is fairly key/essential is to make sure you also provide a transcription (weren't Youtube trialling an automated way of doing this at some point?) since obviously search engines cannot determine words from audio to be taken into account when ranking content (for now, at least).

Comment: "a good start". Yes, but that's my question: what to fill? which keyword in which place? what is a optimal length?

Comment: The optimal length is the length it takes to provide users an appropriate description or list of keywords pertaining of your video.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword - YouTube will start suggesting keywords as you fill-in content.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: YouTube will auto-suggest keywords when you start inserting keywords and details about the video you uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read [Vlogger Academy's Youtube SEO guide](https://www.vloggeracademy.net/guide/video-seo/). It will help you to understand the basics of video seo on YT. After you finished the base guide, also read the detailed articles about video tagging, description and video title writing.

*In a nutshell, please check the following ranking factors that I copied from the linked material:*

***Metadata:***

- Video title
- Video description
- Video tags

***User interactions:***

- Video views
- Video comments
- Video likes

***Channel related:***

- Subscriber number